# How to update the enumerable of an object property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, hashtable, enumerable

I define a object as follows:

```js
var obj = {};
var name = "nonenumerable";
var value = "hello world";

Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {value: value,
  writable : true,
  enumerable : false,
  configurable : true
});

console.log(obj); 
//output in code snippet console: {}
//output in browser console: { nonenumerable: "hello world" }
```

Now i want to store the object into my local storage with

```
localStorage.setItem("localObj", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

I know that JsonObjects do not include "non enumerables", consequently my property is not stored. My problem is that i use the object as a kind of "hashtable".

```js
var obj = {
  1: { id: 1, start: 3, end: 6 },
  2: { id: 2, start: 5, end: 8 },
  3: { id: 3, start: 2, end: 4 }
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "all", {value: {},
  writable : true,
  enumerable : false,
  configurable : true
});
obj.all.start = 0;
obj.all.end = 10;

function setStart(id, add){
  if(add) obj[id].start += 1;
  else obj[id].start -= 1
  updateContent("start", id, obj[id].start);
}

function setAllStart(start, add){
  if(add) obj.all.start += 1;
  else obj.all.start -= 1
  updateContent("start", "all", obj.all.start);
  for(id in obj){
    obj[id].start = obj.all.start;
    updateContent("start", id, obj[id].start);
  }
}

function setEnd(id, add){
  if(add) obj[id].end += 1;
  else obj[id].end -= 1
  updateContent("end", id, obj[id].end);
}

function setAllEnd(start, add){
  if(add) obj.all.end += 1;
  else obj.all.end -= 1
  updateContent("end", "all", obj.all.end);
  for(id in obj){
    obj[id].end = obj.all.end;
    updateContent("end", id, obj[id].end);
  }
}

function updateContent(selector, id, content){
   document.querySelector("#" + selector + "-" + id).innerHTML = content;
}
```

```css
.value {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  AllStart:
  <button type="button" onclick="setAllStart(3, false);">-</button>
  <div id="start-all" class="value">0</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setAllStart(3, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  AllEnd:
  <button type="button" onclick="setAllEnd(3, false);">-</button>
  <div id="end-all" class="value">10</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setAllEnd(3, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  Start 1:
  <button type="button" onclick="setStart(1, false);">-</button>
  <div id="start-1" class="value">3</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setStart(1, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  End 1:
  <button type="button" onclick="setEnd(1, false);">-</button>
  <div id="end-1" class="value">6</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setEnd(1, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  Start 2:
  <button type="button" onclick="setStart(2, false);">-</button>
  <div id="start-2" class="value">5</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setStart(2, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  End 2:
  <button type="button" onclick="setEnd(2, false);">-</button>
  <div id="end-2" class="value">8</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setEnd(2, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  Start 3:
  <button type="button" onclick="setStart(3, false);">-</button>
  <div id="start-3" class="value">2</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setStart(3, true);">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  End 3:
  <button type="button" onclick="setEnd(3, false);">-</button>
  <div id="end-3" class="value">4</div>
  <button type="button" onclick="setEnd(3, true);">+</button>
</div>
```

My questions:

1) Can i update the `enumerable` of my property to `true` after defineProperty ?

2) Can i step over the "nonenumerable" key if its defined as `obj.all = {}` in the `for-loop` without an `if-statement`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `for...in` only "loops" through the enumerables - doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. Thats why i define the property "all" as "nonenumerable".

Comment: so, what's the issue? why does it need to "become" enumerable? `obj.all` does have the value `helloworld!` - if you create it with `enumerable: true` - the previous loop wont be called retrospectively

Comment: I updated the code snippet. I need a function to change all values at once and to change each value by themself. Thats why definde the `obj.all` with  `enumerable: false` Then i need to store it in the localStorage, to use the data on a second page. When i go back to the selection-page i need to know the values for "all" again as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helper function

```
function load(inp) {
    var spec = function (o) {
        Object.defineProperty(o, 'all', { 
            writable: true,
            enumerable: false,
            configurable : true,
            value: o.all || {}
        });
        Object.defineProperty(o, "toString", {
            value: function () {
                Object.defineProperty(this, 'all', { enumerable: true});
                var ret = JSON.stringify(this);
                Object.defineProperty(this, 'all', { enumerable: false});
                return ret;
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
    return spec(typeof inp == "string" ? JSON.parse(inp) : inp);
}
```

you can initialise the object like this

```
var obj = load({
    1: { id: 1, start: 3, end: 6 },
    2: { id: 2, start: 5, end: 8 },
    3: { id: 3, start: 2, end: 4 }
});
obj.all.start = 0;
obj.all.end = 10;
```

or even like this

```
var obj1 = load({
    1: { id: 1, start: 3, end: 6 },
    2: { id: 2, start: 5, end: 8 },
    3: { id: 3, start: 2, end: 4 },
    all: {
        start: 0,
        end: 10
    }
});
```

to store it

```
localStorage.setItem('testing', obj)
```

to load it from storage

```
var obj2 = load(localStorage.getItem('testing'));

console.log(obj.toString() == obj2.toString());
// true
```

Comment: That is a really nice solution and the helper function is really nice. I allready solved the problem, but this is allmost similar to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.defineProperty()` can also be used to modify the descriptor of an existing property. For your use case, a better aproach would be to serialize a copy of the original object:

```
var open = {};
Object.assign(open, obj);
open.all = obj.all;
localStorage.setItem("localObj", JSON.stringify(open));
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that i can modify the descriptor of an existing property. Unfortunetly i cannot use a copy of the object, because i would need to merge the object with the clone when i load them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer of ccprog i can use to `Object.defineProperty()` to modify my object property.

```js
var obj = {};
var name = "nonenumerable";
var value = "hello world";

Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {value: value,
  writable : true,
  enumerable : false,
  configurable : true
});

console.log(obj); 
//output in code snippet console: {}
//output in browser console: { nonenumerable: "hello world" }


Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
  enumerable : true
});
console.log(obj);
```